# Form of subgroup of G×G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know , subgroup of G×G is not of the form H×K.

diagonal subgroup support my statement.

My question when can we say that  subgroup of G×G is of the form H ×K?  Is there any sufficient conditions? Or is there any necessary and sufficient conditions?

Of course here G is a group and H, K be two subgroups of G.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have answered the question yourself. The answer is never (except when $|G|=1$), becuase there is a diagonal subgroup for every group $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think the OP may have meant to ask whether there are conditions ( on the subgroup itself or on the group $\;G\;$)  that make sure some subgroup of  $\;G\times G\;$ is of the form $\;H\times K\;$ , with $\;H,\,K\le G\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio  yes I wanna ask that...  Is there??

Comment: @Siraj Not that I am aware of...and if there is one I'm sure Derek knows.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is that $H$ and $K$ have no common nontrivial quotient group. An easier sufficient condition is that they have coprime orders. Sorry I don't have time to write a proof right now.

Comment: Ok,,  take time..  While u are free kindly write a proof..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma